# How change the image of open Dialog box and how to customize Dialog box in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, openfiledialog

When I open file that show the dialog box, I need to change Java image and add my own image. How to customize dialog box?

For example, I need to add the Encoding to the dialog box and how to add different type of files to Files of type dropdown box. For Example, i add `text`, `java`, `html` to `Files of type` box.

Here is my code,

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(OpenExample.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Swing's file chooser is `JFileChooser`.  The `FileDialog` is pure AWT.  See [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details and examples of using the Swing file chooser.

Comment: put JFileChooser to JDialog with required settings

Comment: thank you for reply, through filedialog is not possiable. how to change the java theme image.@mKorbel and @AndrewThompson

Comment: Look is good for FileDialog.@AndrewThompson

Comment: how to change the image and customize the FileChooser or FileDialog. can you provide the example? please @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide an icon for a file chooser or dialog, set an icon for the parent frame.

[image]

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileChooserIcon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // see nice icons in chooser!
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {}
                JLabel ui = new JLabel("Big Space");
                ui.setBorder(new javax.swing.EmptyBorder(40, 200, 40, 200));

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Show file chooser icon");
                f.setIconImage(new BufferedImage(
                        20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(ui);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);

                JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
                jfc.showOpenDialog(f); // use frame icon!
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

---

> .. how to add different type of files to Files of type dropdown box? For example: add `text`, `java`, `html` to `Files of type` box.

See [How to Use File Choosers: FileChooserDemo2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#advancedexample__1) which offers a file filter for `Just Images`..

[image]